# KeyboardAvoidingView: Warning checkPropTypes has been moved to a separate package

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native with Expo. Everytime I import and use a KeyboardAvoidingView, I get the following warning:

> KeyboardAvoidingView: Warning checkPropTypes has been moved to a
>   separate package.

**How can I fix this warning?**

I'm using:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1  
react-native: 0.45.1
```

Comment: The warning is self explanatory , few releases back , react moved propTypes outside in a separate library and since then , this warning is shown , coming from KeyboardAvoidingView , you have to pretty much ignore this till they fix it or can raise a pull request yourself :)

Comment: That's what I guessed indeed, I was wondering if there wasn't a better solution than waiting for them to update :).

Comment: what version are you on react-native, i am using latest and not getting the same error.

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1  
react-native: 0.45.1

Comment: try react-native 0.46, i am using that only and not getting any warning

Comment: @ArnavYagnik great answer!